# Why is Ripple's base58 alphabet so weird?

Tags: ripple, address, standard, encoding

In [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/7599/323) I found out that Ripple uses a different base58 alphabet from Bitcoin. There aren't many materials on what that alphabet is, but I managed to find [this reference](https://ripple.com/wiki/Encodings):

> The base58 dictionary for ripple is: rpshnaf39wBUDNEGHJKLM4PQRST7VWXYZ2bcdeCg65jkm8oFqi1tuvAxyz

I am wondering - why is Ripple's alphabet so bizarre in comparison to Bitcoin's base58 alphabet:

> 123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

I understand that for some branding reasons one would want to put "r" as a letter for 0 and use 0 as network byte for Ripple (thus making every address start with "r"), but the same could've been accomplished by simply shifting the alphabet like so:

> rstuvwxyz123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopq

What is the logic behind the odd alphabet letter order?

Comment: Interestingly, if you look at just the capital letters they are almost in ascending order, as are just the small letters.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know about the rest of the string but I think the leading bytes are ordered that way to make the types of "addresses" be human reconizable.

From a quick look at the source I think the leading characters, `rpshnaf` map like so:

- r = public Ripple address
- p = node private
- s = Ripple secret
- h = ?
- n = node public
- a = address family generator or seed ?
- f = address family generator or seed ?

Of these, wallet owners have seen the r* and s* "addresses" and those running ripple will be have seen the n* and p* ones.